# Is it possible to parse an .apk file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, python, apk

We have Python code that parses .apk files. We want to do it in JavaScript and then upload the file directly to S3. Is it possible? And if yes, how do we do it? We can use existing plugins if necessary.

Here is the Python code that parses the files:

```
import os
import urllib2
import StringIO
import re

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile

from androguard.core.bytecodes.apk import APK
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

from parser import Parser


class APKParser(Parser):

    def __init__(self, filepath):
        if filepath.startswith("http://") or filepath.startswith("https://"):
            conn = urllib2.urlopen(filepath)
            self.apk = APK(conn.read(), raw=True)
            conn.close()
        else:
            self.apk = APK(filepath)
        self.apk_xml = self.apk.get_AndroidManifest()

    def get_version(self):
        manifest = self.apk_xml.getElementsByTagName("manifest")[0]
        return manifest.getAttribute("android:versionName")

    def get_name(self):
        app = self.apk_xml.getElementsByTagName("application")[0]
        name = app.getAttribute("android:label")
        if name.startswith("@"):
            package_parser = self.apk.get_android_resources()
            name = ''
            for package_name in package_parser.get_packages_names():
                name = package_parser.get_string(package_name, 'app_name')
                if name:
                    name = name[1]
                    break
        return name

    def get_package_name(self):
        return self.apk.package

    def get_image(self, content_item):
        storage = S3BotoStorage(bucket=settings.AWS_MANAGED_CONTENT_SETS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
                                secure_urls=settings.SECURE_IMAGES_URL)
        filepath = ""
        for apk_file in self.apk.get_files():
            if re.match("(res/drawable.*/(icon|logo).*)", apk_file):
                filepath = apk_file
                break
        if filepath:
            try:
                fileext = os.path.splitext(filepath)[1][1:]
                file_io = StringIO.StringIO()
                file_io.write(self.apk.get_file(filepath))
                icon_filename = "%s.%s" % (self.get_name(), fileext)
                inmemory_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(file_io, None, icon_filename, 'image/%s' % fileext,
                                                     file_io.len, None)
                inmemory_file.seek(0)
                upl_file = uploaded_filename(content_item, inmemory_file.name)
                storage._save(upl_file, inmemory_file)
                file_io.close()
                return dict(url=storage.url(upl_file), path=upl_file)
            except:
                pass
        return dict()
```

Comment: `Is it possible?` Yes.

Comment: "And if yes, how do we do it?" -- what is "it"? Write JavaScript? Write an Android app? UnZIP an APK? Something else? Note that asking for off-site resources is now off-topic for Stack Overflow -- use [the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) for requests for existing libraries.

Comment: @CommonsWare We need to extract the version, name, package name and image from it.

Comment: If you are the author of the APK, you already have this information. If you are not the author of the APK, you should be contacting the authors for this information.

Comment: We want to parse APK files uploaded by users.

Answer (score 1):

An APK file is just a [ZIP file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29) that contains a bunch of XML files, assets, and class files. Javascript can read XML file no problem, but it needs external library to decompress zip file. It will be quite difficult to decode the class files, but I guess you probably wouldn't need to do that.

The only difficulty though, if you need to recompress the file after modification. If you don't want security warning, you may need to resign the package (which may be impossible unless you have the original private key). You also need to be able to generate the APK metadata. This can be quite difficult.

Comment: We don't need to modify the file, only to extract the version, name, package name and image from it.